# How do tell setuptools to get my package from src/mypackage

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a package directory setup like this

```
package_dir
|-src
| |-mypackage
|   |-__init__.py
|
|-setup.py
```

How do I set up `setup.py` to enable me to `import mypackage`

I've tried: I run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` where `setup.py` has options...

```
packages=find_packages(include=["src"]),
package_dir={"": "src"},
```

When I run pip install path/to/mypackage.whl it installs fine
But when I do `python -c "import mypackage"` it fails with `ModuleNotFoundError`
while `python -c "import src.mypackage"` is fine

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
find_packages(where='src')
```

Use `where`, not `include`. `exclude/include` are for further filtering found packages. See:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from setuptools import find_packages
>>> find_packages()
[]
>>> find_packages(include=['src'])
[]
>>> find_packages(where='src')
['mypackage']
```

Comment: This solved my problem!  In the current state of packaging, this is valuable information.